# How to grep for "STRING1" but skip if the line contains "STRING2"?

Tags: grep, search

I want to search for "STRING1" using `grep` but to skip if the line contains "STRING2". How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
 grep -v "STRING2" file | grep "STRING1"
```

Comment: guillermo chamorro's answer is more efficient that searching for STRING1 then discarding the result if STRING2 is present.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using `awk` or `perl` instead of `grep`

Ex.

```
awk '/STRING1/ && !/STRING2/' file
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if /STRING1/ && !/STRING2/' file
```

See also [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators) .